# Renci.sshnet Hash issue

Tags: c#, ssh

I have been working on a script to SSH into a couple network devices. I cam across a device that every time my program ssh into it, the device reboots.  Sshnet shows that i do have a connection but after 30 seconds the device reboots.

I tried using putty to manually hit the device and it works every time. I pulled some wireshark captures of both the program and putty. What I did notice is that putty uses the following encryption and mac

SSH Version 2 (encryption:aes256-ctr mac:hmac-sha2-256 compression:none)

When I run my C# code it uses

SSH Version 2 (encryption:aes256-ctr mac:hmac-sha1 compression:none)

here is my code

```
SshClient sshclient = new SshClient(strIpAddress, 22, strUser, strPassword);
           try
           {
               sshclient.Connect();
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {

               Debug.Print(sshclient.ToString());
           }

           if (sshclient.IsConnected)
           {
               // do good things 
               sshclient.Disconnect();
               sshclient.Dispose();
           }
           else
           {
               //failed
           }
```

Comment: Cheap hardware? Maybe a different algoritm causes the device to use more resources and the lack of resources causes it to reboot. Another posibility would be some random error raised on the device handling SHA1, perhaps a non intended buffer overflow.

Comment: That was my thought, but putty uses SHA2 and the sshnet script is using SHA1. I am connecting to the same device with both options(putty/C#)  from the same computer.

Comment: What about the other alternative? The device handling poorly SHA1 and causing it to crash? A buffer overflow most likely would lead to a wrong memory state that could potentially hang or reboot the system